# How does Bing know when a result is clicked to use in website ranking?

Tags: bing, ctr

I know that Google uses redirect links to count clicks ie:

```
https://www.google.com/url?q=http://html5test.com/&sa=U&ei=xlezU6DPIsqysQS824HwAg&ved=0CB0QFjAB&usg=AFQjCNEMhjMTe0TBrbgGmG6mlSygIF-mww
```

but Bing doesn't do this it instead gives you the actual link to the page. [This page](http://www.themediaflow.com/blog/bing-ranking-algorithm-includes-ctr) explaining Bings algorithm says it takes CTR into account

Comment: Did you view the source code? Maybe they use JavaScript? I see an HTML attribute that indicates they do. That article is also old. Got a newer source?

Comment: sorry no newer source. I don't think it's javascript... at least I don't think so. I did a test with Live HTTP Headers and I didn't see any info being sent off via javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Bing appears to use AJAX to track clicks.

I used the Firefox plugin [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) and observed what happened when I clicked on a result in Bing.   The search result page did a post request with an XML payload with lots of information about what I clicked on:

```
http://www.bing.com/fd/ls/lsp.aspx

POST /fd/ls/lsp.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.bing.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://www.bing.com/search?q=hello&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=hello&sc=8-5&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=59661aced04d46f1b80899410929857c
Content-Length: 1440
Cookie: _HOP=; _EDGE_S=F=1; _EDGE_V=1; _FS=NU=1; _SS=SID=FAC9D0DA20004A6A8613CA3C3CB2C0FC&C=20&bIm=748094&R=1; MUID=125A1E6D6A37680D3F6718066B2668F7; MUIDB=125A1E6D6A37680D3F6718066B2668F7; SRCHD=SM=1&MS=3419186&D=3419186&AF=NOFORM; SRCHUID=V=2&GUID=40090526FFAC48B7881D86F22F6A47B4; SRCHUSR=AUTOREDIR=0&GEOVAR=&DOB=20140702; SRCHHPGUSR=CW=1351&CH=646; SCRHDN=ASD=0&DURL=#; FBS=WTS=1404296809175&CR=-1; _RwBf=s=70&o=16; WLS=TS=63539893612; DUP=Q=nk50aHNbaDqVspSh41v5&T=205151212&IG=555b1d13f5864ff98c4f311e7ab75b3b&V=1&A=2
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
<ClientInstRequest><Events><E><T>Event.ClientInst</T><IG>555b1d13f5864ff98c4f311e7ab75b3b</IG><TS>1404296823845</TS><D>{"T": "CI.BoxModel", "FID": "CI", "Name": "Perf", "Text": "S%3A0X0X1351X646%3BBODY.%20%3A0X0X1351X1644%3BNAV.b_scopebar%3A0X0X1351X30%3BH1.b_logo%3A17X44X73X29%3BDIV.b_searchboxForm%3A100X40X560X37%3BDIV%23id_h%3A845X0X300X30%3BDIV%23b_tween%3A100X91X1251X30%3BSPAN.sb_count%3A120X91X152X30%3BSPAN.ftrB%3A272X91X116X30%3BOL%23b_results%3A100X121X560X1473%3BLI.b_algo%3A100X121X560X93%3BLI.b_algo%3A100X216X560X111%3BLI.b_ans%3A100X329X560X192%3BLI.b_algo%3A100X524X560X93%3BLI.b_algo%3A100X619X560X93%3BLI.b_ans%3A100X715X560X231%3BLI.b_algo%3A100X947X560X93%3BLI.b_algo%3A100X1043X560X93%3BLI.b_algo%3A100X1138X560X117%3BLI.b_algo%3A100X1257X560X93%3BLI.b_ans%3A100X1353X560X139%3BLI.b_pag%3A100X1494X560X98%3BOL%23b_context%3A690X121X455X818%3BLI.b_ans%3A690X121X455X428%3BLI.b_ans%3A690X554X455X129%3BLI.b_ans%3A690X688X455X246%3BFOOTER.b_footer%3A0X1614X1351X104%3BIMG%23id_p%3A0X0X0X0XEX1X-1%3BIMG%23emb1%3A121X386X120X68XEX120X-1%3BIMG%23emb2%3A242X386X120X68XEX120X-1%3BIMG%23emb3%3A363X386X120X68XEX120X-1%3BIMG%23emb4%3A484X386X120X68XEX120X-1%3BIMG%23emb5%3A120X770X80X80XEX80X-1%3BIMG%23emb6%3A120X1195X50X50XEX50X-1%3BIMG.rms_img%3A710X170X110X110XBX110X-1%3BIMG.rms_img%3A710X598X75X75XBX75X-1%3BIFRAME%3A1351X1641X0X0XB%3BIFRAME%3A0X0X0X0XWl%3B"}</D></E></Events><STS>1404296823845</STS></ClientInstRequest>
```